# How do I run Etherdelta locally?

Tags: etherdelta

I have the files from the github repo, which look primarily like client-side files.

I assume there is no backend - the client just interacts with the Etherdelta smart contracts.

The index.html file in the repo redirects to https://etherdelta.com, which is not what I need :)

What are the steps for getting set up locally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, the paths they include are assuming you are running EtherDelta on a root URL.  One easy way to do this is with python:

```
cd /path/to/etherdelta/repo
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 222
```

You may to use `sudo` on the last line.  This will start a server running on port `222`.

You can then navigate to `http://localhost:222/index_com.html` to acccess EtherDelta.

You are correct that this is just client-side code.  It still connects to the remote EtherDelta API.  I don't think they've open-sourced the backend server.

Comment: EtherDelta is not open source.